# View style change when add them with button

Tags: xml, android-studio

I have create a block xml:

[xml block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcmrC.png)

I want add this block when the user click the botton.

The java code:

```
private Button add_Link;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ip);

    final LinearLayout myContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_container); //layout presente nell'mainLayout
    add_Link = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add_link);
    add_Link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //al click del bottone vengono inseriti nuovi campi per l'inserimento di un ulteriore link
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup new_block = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_block, myContainer, false);
            myContainer.addView(new_block);

        }
    });

}
```

But on the hardware device and the emulator this is display:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX36u.png)

The first block isn't create with button but is already present in the file XML R.layout.activity_ip while the second block is create with the button.
The problem is obvius... Why when add the block with button the style of my view change? I want all the same.
Thank for your help.

EDIT:

I tried to create a simple EditText in the onCreate method and not in onClick and the EditText has white background with underscore...The problem probably is in Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved. In the method .from I have used v.getContext like Context